# Flutter Validate animation in the middle of the screen

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, animation

I have an app in which user, on the account page, can't change their nickname. I Want that, when they do that, a validate icon appears, with an animation, like getting bigger or turn on itself, in a circle, and after the animation, it disappears or at best, the validate icons draw slowly. like : [image]

Like to validate the changes of the nickname. It would appears in the middle of the screen.

Something like that:
[image]

Do you have any idea on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create such animations in Flutter Flare.
Check out https://pub.dev/packages/flare_flutter

Create an animation on https://flare.rive.app/ and export using the export engine, or you can find ready resources on https://flare.rive.app/explore/popular/trending/all

once you get the .flr file from there, your can import it into your flutter app using the `flare_flutter` plugin. To make the animation disappear, you can directly hide the widget in flutter.

```
import 'package:flare_flutter/flare_actor.dart';
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new FlareActor("assets/Filip.flr", alignment:Alignment.center, fit:BoxFit.contain, animation:"idle");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! And can you edit your answer to make an exemple of what I asked with this package please ??  Because I don't know to to show it, event with basic animation (Because I want it to disappear after the animation)